# Authenticating with an OAuth 2.0 API

Tags: c#, api, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to write a small service to get data from the [Fitbark](http://www.fitbark.com) service. I've got an API key but don't know where to start with their API. It's documented [here](https://www.fitbark.com/dev/#tab-id-2), but I've never done anything with 3-legged oauth before. I'm a competent coder but this is just a bit new to me. Any suggestions on where to start or examples of coding with this setup?

Comment: All the steps are there, have you attempted to follow them, where did you get to? and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Please edit your question with what you have already tried/got to.